# Вынос css в постзагрузку

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

на сайте получился достаточно большой файл со стилями, я решил выделить минимальные(важные) стили в отдельный файл. Этот файл подключил как обычно через . А вот что делать с оставшимся файлом?

Возможно ли подключить его через js(создать  со стилем через jquery).
Найти другого способа не могу, т.к. css можно подключать только в

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

P.S В гугле ответа не нашел

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать? Из вопроса не очень понятно)

Comment: По аналогии с js: ключевые стили подключаете в `head`, вторичные перед закрытием `body`

Comment: Лучше все в одном файле... И подключить в `head`...

Comment: @MedvedevDev А ведь css можно подключить только через тег <link>, причем только в голове

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Сделать постзагрузку css файлов, после того как основная часть контента будет загружениа

Comment: в реалиях html5 это не так, `link` может использоваться в `body` как часть потока, читать [ТУТ](http://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Comment: @MedvedevDev Спасибо, можете оформить это как ответ на вопрос(я новичок на стаке, не знаю как это на рейтинг влияет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В реалиях HTML5 `<link rel="stylesheet"/>` может использоваться как в `<head></head>` так и в `<body></body>` (сделано как раз для оптимизации загрузки), посему можно основные стили подключить в `head` перед отрисовкой основных элементов, а в конце подключить вспомогательные стили, что бы они загрузились уже после рендера страницы.

Информация взята [ЗДЕСЬ](http://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Comment: А какова поддержка браузерами этой реальности HTML5? Вопрос без подвоха, просто насколько я помню, стили, записанные таким образом, все равно собираются браузерами, загружаются синхронно и рендерятся сразу.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, на столько не углублялся, но на сколько знаю: разметка читается построчно, как только встречается линк или скрипт, происходит его загрузка, не беря в расчет возможность асинхронной загрузки, одновременно загружаться может не более 1 (или 2, опять же не уверен) ресурсов за раз, при этом дальнейшее чтение разметки на этот период приостанавливается. Так что в концепции описанной выше все должно работать как требуется (опять же, если я прав). Что же касается поддержки - тут сложнее, не нашел особо инфы конкретно по этой "фиче" =/